problem installing Rspec with factory_bot. Factories are not registered
I am using rails 7.1.3.4 with rspec-rails 6.1.3 and factory bot.
I have added require 'factory_bot_rails' and   config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods in spec/spec_helper.rb
Here is my factory in spec/factories/message.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :message do
    body { 'some reply to the message' }
    read { false }
  end
end

And here is the test in spec/models/message_spec.rb
describe 'message' do
  let(:message) { create(:message) }
  it 'is created unread' do
    expect(message.read).to be false
  end
end

When I type rspec in the terminal I have this error :
Failures:

  1) message is created unread
     Failure/Error: let(:message) { create(:message) }

     KeyError:
       Factory not registered: "message"

I'm not sure what I should do to be able to use the factory.
EDIT in rails c FactoryBot.factories['message'] does return a factory_bot factory

content of .rspec file
--color
--require spec_helper
--require rails_helper

spec/rails_helper.rb should contain
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

content of spec/support/factory_bot.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end

Everything should work

It changes nothing the error is the same. I have to add require 'factory_bot_rails to spec/support/factory_bot otherwise the error become : uninitialized constant FactoryBot

Filename for factory should be spec/factories/messages.rb, but this does not really matter, 2) did you add factory bot to group :test in Gemfile? because it should return uninitialized constant FactoryBot in development for me

The gem is in group :development, :test

Make sure to Add:
require 'factories/*.rb' inside spec_helper.rb
[Also try:
let(:message) { FactoryBot.create(:message) }
]
